# Add UIView To Tableview cell not updating

Tags: swift, tableview

I am trying to add a UIView to an existing IBOutlet in a tableview cell. However this does not appear until I have scrolled away from the cell and scroll back to it.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let stockCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "stockCell", for: indexPath) as! customStockCell

    let progressBar = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    progressBar.backgroundColor = .green
    stockCell.progressContainerView.addSubview(progressBar)

    return cell
}



class customStockCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var progressContainerView: UIView!
}
```

Comment: Apart from the issue be aware that you are adding a new view whenever the cell is being reused. You should check whether the view already exists.

Comment: Thanks, that's not part of the issue and I'm aware how to address it, so I haven't included that code in this question.

Comment: Why are you adding a `UIView` object to the cell inside the `cellForRowAt` delegate method?  What is the purpose of the progressBar guy?  If necessary, make a subclass of the `UITableViewCell` guy and do it there.

Comment: For all my coding life I've always done most of the setup in the cellForRow part. Is that not where I should do these type of things?

Answer (score 0):

Using *contentView* instead of *containerView* works fine for me.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let stockCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "stockCell", for: indexPath)
    
        let progressBar = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        progressBar.backgroundColor = .green
        stockCell.containerView.addSubview(progressBar)
    
        return cell
    }
```

You can also create a custom cell class and add this logic inside its' initialiser.

Alternatively, if the above solution doesn't work, you can add this logic inside `willDisplayCell:`

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let progressBar = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    progressBar.backgroundColor = .green
    cell.containerView.addSubview(progressBar)
  }
```

Comment: Sorry "containerView" is a custom class/IB Outlet UIView already in the tableview cell. Will update code to reflect this.

Comment: Could you please share the 'customStockCell' class code?